# Como salvar informações igual o pprint em um arquivo txt

Tags: python, log

Estou criando uma função para gerar um arquivo de log:

```
def setLog(msg):
    file = open(nome_arquivo, adicionar_informacao)
    if type(msg) == str:
        msg_log = msg.encode('utf-8');
    else:
        try:
            msg_log = str(msg).encode('utf-8');
        except:
            msg_log = type(msg).__name__.encode('utf-8');
    file.write(msg_log)
    file.write("\n")
    file.close()
    echo(msg_log)
```

Informações do tipo string obviamente são salvas no arquivo tranquilamente, mas eu queria pegar qualquer coisa.

Por exemplo, tenho este método:

```
def socketConnect(self):
        try:
            self.__ffChatSocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
            self.__ffChatSocket.connect((self.__ip, self.__port))
            self.__ffChatSocket.send(self.criarEvento("onCompleteConnection", [self.getNumeroFuturoFone()]))
            thread.start_new_thread(self.socketReceiveData, ())
        except Exception as erro:
            setLog("[ socketConnect ] erro: ")
            setLog(erro)
            self.reconectarSocket()
```

Eu envio desta forma o erro setLog(erro), mas não consigo pegar este erro, se eu utilizo o pprint eu consigo enxergar todas as informação.

Eu queria algo igual o pprint mas salvando em um arquivo .txt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Descobri como fazer, existe um método dentro do próprio pprint que faz isso o pformat.

```
from pprint import pformat

saida = pformat(valor).encode('utf-8');
```